# Ionic 3 ionic radio button display options near each other using flex

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I need to put radio button options near each other:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list radio-group>
        <ion-list-header>
            Auto Manufacturers
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of array">

            <ion-radio (click)="getVal()" slot="start" [value]="entry"></ion-radio>
            <ion-label>&nbsp; {{entry}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I tried to use flex but it didn't work:

`display: flex`

The current behavior is 2 options beneath each other. But how can I use flex to display them near each other?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-eqidsh)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use grid system to achieve this:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list radio-group>
  <ion-list-header>
     Auto Manufacturers
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let entry of array">
      <ion-item >
        <ion-radio (click)="getVal()" slot="start" [value]="entry"></ion-radio>
       <ion-label>&nbsp; {{entry}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please add an reference to your answer where you got this from